# $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to an interval

Tags: general-topology

Use connectedness to show that a unit circle, $S^{1}$ is not homeomorphic to any type (open, half-interval, closed) interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

What I have so far...Let $X$ be $S^{1}$. Let Y be any type of interval of $\mathbb{R}$. I want to show that if $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$ and $x \in X$ then there is a $y \in Y$ such that $X-\{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $Y- \{y\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f$ is a homeomorphism of $S^1$ onto an interval $Y$. Take $x\in S^1$, and consider the spaces $S^{1}\setminus \{x\}$, $Y\setminus \{f(x)\}$. Which of these spaces are connected? What can you say about the function $f$ restricted to $S^1\setminus\{x\}$? Can you get a contradiction?

Comment: $Y \setminus f(x)$ is disconnected; however $S^{1} \setminus x$ is still connected. The function $f$ restricted to $S^{1} \setminus x$ is still continuous because it is an imbedding of the homeomorphism. There is a contradiction because the image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected, but in this case it is not, since $Y \setminus f(x)$ is disconnected. Is that right?

Comment: That's the basic idea. You do need to treat the case that $Y$ is closed and $f(x)$ is an endpoint of the interval, in which case $Y\setminus f(x)$ might not be disconnected. (The cases where $Y$ is half-open or open are easily taken care of, because $S^1$ is compact.)

Answer (score 2):

Roughly: If you pick out a point from $S^1$ then it is still a single  connected piece, but if you pick out a point from the interval it is a two disconnected piece.